# Will modules be part of C++20 ? Will it reduce compilation time for libraries?

Tags: c++, build, compilation, c++20

Hi I am full time c++ programmer with 2.5 years experience. I felt good about new C++14 features. I use them everyday. However every time I compile my code it takes lot of time some time even more than 15 min. I went through the guidelines on how to reduce compile time using Forward References, Pre-compiled headers etc.. However it still take long time to compile even for small c++ projects which I like to try some logic/new feature or a library.
I read little about modules which didn't make it to C++17. I am just curious to know will it be part of C++20 ? Will it reduce compilation time ?If so by how much factor ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the fate of modules is not decided yet. But I guess the real question here is how to reduce compilation time...

Comment: Take a look at [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org) - it helps *a lot*.

Comment: Also [distcc](https://github.com/distcc/distcc#distcc----a-free-distributed-cc-compiler-system) may be worth looking at.

Comment: At present (time I write this) it is not known IF C++20 will support modules or, if it does, how it will change from current proposals.  One of the objectives of modules is reducing compilation time.   How well that is achieved will depend on a lot of factors - so remains to be seen.   Poor compiler implementations may mean negligible improvement of compilation times.   How modules are specified (e.g. how easy or difficult is it for a compiler vendor to comply with the standard) might also result in difficulty achieving the expected benefits.

Answer (score 2):

From the second edition of "A Tour of C++":

> The language feature, called modules is not yet ISO C++, but it is an ISO Technical Specification [ModulesTS]. Implementations are in use, so I risk recommending it here even though details are likely to change and it may be years before everybody can use it in production code. -- *Bjarne Stroustrup, [A Tour of C++, June 2018](http://www.informit.com/store/tour-of-c-plus-plus-9780134997834)*.

And while factors will vary, Dr. Stroustrup notes:

> The effects on maintainability and compile-time performance can be spectacular.